# using c++ and php together

Tags: php, c++, c

I coded php script ( it runs slow because of many mysql queries etc) but I want to run php files/queries faster with using C++ in PHP files. Is there some documents for that (example codes etc)?

Comment: very malformed question. but check facebook's HipHop https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/

Answer (score 2):

C++ is not going to help you run MySQL queries faster. Your queries are still the bottle neck. Changing your database structure, indexing, caching, etc are all going to make a much larger impact.

Howeve, if you wish to interface a C++ method to your PHP application, you can use SWIG: http://swig.org

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to improve MySQL queries, however it will increase overall server load by a noticeable bit. Take a look at http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/358/

This has become open source and basically works as a translator of php to c++. Works quiet well from what I hear.